# Render GSP in filter is not working

Tags: grails, filter

I'm trying to render a .GSP view inside the view folder from my filter. The following code show that:

```
def filters = {
   all(controller:'*', action:'*') {

      afterView = { Exception e ->

         if (controllerName) {
            //some code here

            if (annotation!=null) {
               switch(response.format){

                  case 'all':
                     if(!response.containsHeader("AC_MSG")|| !response.containsHeader("AC_STATUS")){

                        render(view: "/internalerror", model: [controller: controllerName,action:currentAction,
                               message:"Response doesn't contain required headers AC_MSG or AC_STATUS. Either add the required headers or use json format.",
                               example:"Add the following response headers: AC_MSG:response message , AC_STATUS: false or true"
                        ])
                        return false
                     }

                     break
                  default:
                     render status: 406
                     break
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that this page didn't get rendered even the code is executed. The page is on the view directory directly. What I did wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a filter can render a gsp, but controllers can.

A perfect example of what you want to do is available in the docs: [filters](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html)

Basically you create an action inside a controller that renders the page, and the filter just redirects to the action.

case 'all':

```
                 if(!response.containsHeader("AC_MSG")|| !response.containsHeader("AC_STATUS")) {

                    redirect(controller: "someController", action:"someAction")
                    return false
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make ErrorController.groovy and implement action with this render view and params.
In filter use only redirect. Remove 'return false' statement also.

Comment: Could you explain why to use redirect only? and why not to return false?